# New on bitcoin want to try it out

Tags: mining-pools

I finally got an bitcoin account and i wanna try it out! can you guys donate/give bitcoin so i can try it ? 
My bitcoin account.
1MD5FXNdwmPpS2JBWrCJcwHBREtg9dk8Uz

Comment: Hello Angu Ilia, we're a question and answer platform focused on collecting knowledge about cryptocurrencies. Your asking for money is off-topic here, so I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

nice try :-) you may want to look for a "bitcoin faucet", and perform the work yourself. You can earn some Satoshis, which will help you to get started.